# Socket.IO middleware, io.use

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

Working on a web application which is built upon expressJS and Socket.io.
In [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788831/authenticating-socket-io-connections) I saw the usage of middleware syntax which was new to me. Here is an example of the syntax:

```
const io = require('socket.io')();

io.use(function(socket, next) {
  // execute some code
  next();
})
.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // Connection now authenticated to receive further events

    socket.on('message', function(message) {
        io.emit('message', message);
    });
});
```

It basically uses middleware functions on the `socket.io` instance. My previous understanding was that middlware can only be used on the express instance (`app.use(...)`).

### Questions:

1. Is this syntax just regular middleware which works similarly to `app.use(...)`?
2. If it is different, what are the differences?

Comment: I am confused, the callback in 'io.use' has an 'else' but there is no 'if'.

Comment: Yes sorry was a mistake edited it now

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`io.use()` allows you to specify a function that is called for every new, incoming socket.io connection.  It can be used for a wide variety of things such as:

1. Logging
2. Authentication
3. Managing sessions
4. Rate limiting
5. Connection validation

And so on...

It's purpose is similar to Express middleware (like with `app.use()`), but this is for incoming socket.io connections, not incoming the regular http requests that Express manages.  If you want middleware to process an incoming http request, use Express middleware with `app.use()`.  If you want middleware to process an incoming socket.io connection, use socket.io middleware with `io.use()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sometimes Socket.io could use some more documentation IMO.

Comment: @jfriend00 Is it possibile to transform the incoming data inside the io.use() middleware in such a way that the next middleware get them changed?

Comment: I mean, something like socket.use((packet, next) => { packet.foo = 'bar'; next(); });

Comment: @giggioz - ```io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.use((packet, next) => {
    if (packet.doge === true) return next();
    next(new Error('Not a doge error'));
  });
});```

Comment: Note that unlike Express middleware, socket middleware is only ever called once - on a new connection. So using it to do authentication is very limited. It can only validate the initial connection not any subsequent communications.

Comment: @JulianKnight Naturally, as the connections are long lived.

Comment: Version 4.x has middlewares called on every call.

Comment: @PatrickDesjardins - Can you provide a reference for that?  When I look up the [4.x doc](https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/) for `io.use()`, I see this: *Note: this function will be executed only once per connection (even if the connection consists in multiple HTTP requests).*

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation of [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v3/middlewares/) V 3.0.4 a middleware function `io.use` in [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v3/middlewares/) is a function that gets executed for every incoming connection like in [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) but the only difference is that socket manages the request wherein express HTTP protocol manages the request.

**Why socket middleware**

- Middleware functions in socket.io are very useful during
  authentication of request,
- Additional data like credentials can be put in the socket during the connection.
- Middleware function can be used multiple times where each of them runs the given function in order.