# Socket.io, io.use occur before connection is made?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm using the Socket.io use function (https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-use-fn) to authenticate connections, but I'm not sure if I can disconnect a socket from within that function, because I don't know if the connection is made prior to calling 'use'.

Does Socket.io wait until the completion of `io.use` before making the connection? If the authentication fails, how can I stop the connection from being made?

My testing has shown that `io.on('connection')` is not fired until `next()` is called within the 'use' function. But I've also found that when I include `socket.disconnect()` inside of the 'use' function, the client will in fact disconnect, but the server still thinks the client is connected, as shown by `io.clients`.

I've read this SO question which cleared up some details about the 'use' function but didn't address my question: [Socket.IO middleware, io.use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50003748/socket-io-middleware-io-use)

```
io.use(function (socket, next) {
  let token = socket.handshake.query.token;

  if (verify(token) == false) {
    socket.disconnect(); // Can I do this here?
  }

  next();
});

// This isn't fired until the above 'use' function completes, but
// despite disconnecting above, 'on connection' still fires and `io.clients` shows the client is connected
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  setTimeout(function(){

      // Get number of connected clients:
      io.clients((error, clients) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(clients); // => [PZDoMHjiu8PYfRiKAAAF, Anw2LatarvGVVXEIAAAD]
      });

  }, 2000);

});
```

**EDIT**

I have mostly found the answer to this through testing. `next()` should only be called if the authentication succeeds. If it fails, just don't call `next()` and the socket will not connect. However, I do not understand why calling `socket.disconnect()` inside of the 'use' function creates a scenario where the server thinks it's connected to the client, but the client is actually disconnected.