# Socket.io chat login using PHP session

Tags: php, node.js, curl, socket.io, chat

Users are already logged and their username is stored in a PHP session. I'm trying to allow users to chat using Socket.io without having to log in again. For a moment I thought I'd solved the problem using CURL to push the username to the Socket.io server and then redirecting the user with header('Location: http://'.$domain.':3000');

While this does send the needed information to the server it does not restrict it to a single user. So anyone who reloads their Socket.io client page essentially logs in again as the last user who's information was sent via CURL. How can I send the username from the PHP sesion to the Socket.io server and restrict that information to a single user?

PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['member'];

$member = $_SESSION['member'];
$number = $_SESSION['Member_Number'];

$data = array("name" => $member, "number" => $number);                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

$ch = curl_init('http://'.$domain.':3000/push');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 10); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                 
);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


header('Location: http://'.$domain.':3000');
?>
```

SERVER

```
app.all('/push', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.name); // member's name
    console.log(req.body.number); // member's public id

    memberName = req.body.name.trim();
    memberNumber = req.body.number;
});
```

UPDATE: After taking Felix Fong's advice I'm attempting to solve this problem using JSON Web Tokens. Here is the PHP I'm using to create the tokens. I'm still not sure exactly how to get the tokens over to the socket.io server.

```
$header = json_encode(['typ' => 'JWT', 'alg' => 'HS256']);

// Create token payload as a JSON string
$payload = json_encode(['user_id' => 123]);

// Encode Header to Base64Url String
$base64UrlHeader = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($header));

// Encode Payload to Base64Url String
$base64UrlPayload = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($payload));

// Create Signature Hash
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload, 'abC123!', true);

// Encode Signature to Base64Url String
$base64UrlSignature = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($signature));

// Create JWT
$jwt = $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload . "." . $base64UrlSignature;

echo $jwt;
```

Comment: I think a better way to approach thing is to set up a centralized authentication server within one side(PHP or Node) and sharing JWT token between two applications, rather than just sharing cookies session

Comment: Ive never used jwt before but after doing some research I think I get the general idea. I've installed the socketio-jwt module and I'm creating the token using the php code I've added to my origional question. My next question is how exactly do I use the newly created token for authorization in socket.io?

Comment: You can pass the token inside the header within each request you make regards of is a HTTP call or WebSocket call

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Can you point me towards an example or tutorial. I'm really not sure how to accomplish this on my own.

Comment: Hope this StackOverflow might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/36821359/6511655