# How to pass a message while connecting to websocket server on node

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have this code here -

```
const wss = new SocketServer({ express() });

wss.on('connection', ws => {
    console.log('Client connected');
    ws.on('message', msg => {
        console.log('received: %s', msg);
    });
    ws.on('close', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
});
```

Now there are some problems, A D-Dos attack can crash my server.

Is there a way to check a token or something before allowing a stranger to connect to the websocket? Also the socket will be on another domain so cookies won't work.

Or is there a way to disconnect a user if he has not sent the authentication token after connecting.

If it were running and allowing everyone to connect indefinitely, then that's a security risk. Server can be brought down easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Socket.io possible a setup like you need, see [Authenticating socket io connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788831/authenticating-socket-io-connections)

Otherwise you must implement it by your own, but you should follow some standards. The first ugly-hand-made solution that i can think is something like:

```
wss.on('connection', ws => {
    console.log('Client connected');

    isAuthenticated = false

    ws.on('message', msg => {
        if (!isAuthenticated ) {
            // check if message is a token
            // else comunicates back the error
        }

        console.log('received: %s', msg);
    });

    ws.on('close', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
});
```

For the DDos attack, if they have a token they can spam infinite requests: same thing, you should count the incoming massage rate by your own and implementing something like a Throttling policy.

Comment: is there a way to efficiently disconnect a client who does not send message after x seconds of connecting

Comment: after `console.log('Client connected');` you can place `setTimeout(() => ws.close(), 5000)`, and clear that timeout when you receive a message

Comment: Did i helped you in some way?

Comment: Yep, specifically this linked helped - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788831/authenticating-socket-io-connections