# Adding socket.io to an existing Express project (with React on the front)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I have an existing project written in Express, where I've made a messaging system. Everything was working on POST/GET methods (to send and receive the messages).
I wanted to make them appear in real time, so I installed `socket.io` both on the client and server side. In my `server.js` I added these lines:

```
const http = require("http");
const io = require("socket.io");
const server = http.createServer();
const socket = io.listen(server);
```

and changed my `app.listen(...)` into `server.listen(...)`.
Added also:

```
socket.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("New client connected");
    socket.on('test', (test) => {
        console.log('test-test')
    });

    socket.emit('hello', {hello:'hello!'});

        socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log("Client disconnected"));
});
```

On the front part I put such code in the `componentDidMount` method:

```
const socket = socketIOClient();
socket.emit('test', {test:'test!'})
socket.on('hello', () => {
    console.log('aaa')
})
```

Now I got 2 problems. Although the console.log() works correctly, I get an error on the React app:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/sockjs-node/039/lmrt05dl/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

Is that normal?

Also, when I change `app.listen(...)` into `server.listen(...)` in the `server.js` file, my routing stops working. All the POST and GET methods don't work, because the server is responding endlessly. Is that possible to use the socket.io just on a specific method in a specific routing file?

I keep my routes that way: `app.use('/api/user', user);` where user is a router file.

UPDATE:
full server.js require:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');

const user = require('./routes/api/v1/User');
const company = require('./routes/api/v1/Company');

const http = require("http");
const io = require("socket.io");


const app = express();

dotenv.config();
app.use(passport.initialize());
require('./config/seed');

require('./config/passport')(passport);
const server = http.createServer();
const socket = io.listen(server);
```

Comment: Nowhere I am able to spot express()

Comment: Sorry, forgot to paste it. Updated my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not initializing server properly. Try making the following change

```
// const server = http.createServer();
const server = http.createServer(app);
```

and make sure you listen on `server` and not `io`

```
server.listen(PORT_GOES_HERE)
```

[UPDATE]
Working Example:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);
// WARNING: app.listen(80) will NOT work here!

// DO STUFF WITH EXPRESS SERVER
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

For more details check this: https://socket.io/docs/

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Maybe you also know the answer to the second part of my question, if I could receive and emit websockets just inside specific routes? Like, let's say only inside `router.get('/message', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res) => {});`?

Comment: You're looking for namespaces. Read the docs here https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: Feel free to prompt if that doesn't works for you or if it's not what you asked

Comment: Thanks, but as I understand, I couldn't emit a socket.io from inside a route function? I'm asking because I would like to protect this connection with a JWT.

Comment: Resolved my problem combining this answer with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788831/authenticating-socket-io-connections