# How to add authentication before executing socket.on('do something')?

Tags: node.js, sockets, authentication, socket.io, passport.js

In fact, I want to restrict users from connecting to the Socket before logging into the Web.

For api calls, I can use passport.js(session) and do the following to restrict them from using the api before logging in

```
app.get('/login', checkAuth, (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('done');
})

function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.redirect('/')
  }
  next()
}
```

But how can I restrict socket.io connections before logging in, or perform an (auth) operation similar to the above?

```
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('hi', async data => {
      await socket.join('XP');
    });
  });
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788831/authenticating-socket-io-connections-using-jwt

Comment: @Daniel
I have read it before, but I use Session in the system. Is there any libraries that can do something similar to allow socket.io to check authentication?

Comment: How about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532692/how-to-share-sessions-with-socket-io-1-x-and-express-4-x ?