# How to get authenticated user from request param to socket.io in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, ejs, mysql2

for few days I have been trying to figure out how to get the current user so I can pass it to the socket.io emit but to no avail. I am using Passport.js for Authentication, ejs, socket.io, express, MySQL, and node.js. Below is my code.

app.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const toastr = require('express-toastr');
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer);
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const moment = require('moment');
require('dotenv').config();

// Set configuration
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/libs')));
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.SECRET_KEY));
app.use(session({
    secret : process.env.SECRET_KEY,
    saveUninitialized : true,
    resave : true
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(toastr());
app.use(cors());
app.use(fileUpload({
    createParentPath: true
}));
require('./config/passport')(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.errors = req.flash('errors');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    res.locals.values = req.flash('values');
    res.locals.toastr = req.flash('toastr');
    res.locals.moment = moment;
    next();
});
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

// Local files
const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');
const translatorRoutes = require('./routes/translator');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
const indexRoutes = require('./routes/index');
const { ensureAuthenticated } = require('./config/authMiddleware');
const User = require('./app/models/user');

io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log('Socket 1 is connected -- ' + socket.id);
    // socket.on('get-authenticated-user', data => {
    //     console.log(data);
    // });
    socket.on('current-user', (data) => console.log(data));

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('User disconnected');
    });
});

// Routes
app.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, indexRoutes);
app.use('/admin', ensureAuthenticated, adminRoutes);
app.use('/admin', ensureAuthenticated, translatorRoutes);
app.use('/admin', ensureAuthenticated, userRoutes);
// app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
//     const model = new User();
//     model.all([], (err, rows) => {
//         return res.json(rows);
//     });
// });
app.use(indexRoutes);
// app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
// app.use('/admin', translatorRoutes);
// app.use('/admin', userRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);

// 404 Page
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.render('404', { pageTitle: '404 Page not found' });
});

httpServer.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

index.js (Router)

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { getCurrentUser } = require('../config/functions');
const io = require('socket.io');

const socket = io('/');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    socket.emit('get-current-user', req.user);
    res.render('welcome', { pageTitle: 'Welcome!', isLogin: false, user: req.user });
});

module.exports = router;
```

passport.js for Authentication

```js
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const db = require('../app/database/database');
const moment = require('moment');
const io = require('socket.io');

module.exports = (passport) => {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
        db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], (err, rows, fields) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (rows.length <= 0) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Email incorrect' });
            }
            const user = rows[0];
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.passwd, (errm, isMatch) => {
                if (errm) throw errm;
                if (isMatch) {
                    // io.emit('get-current-user', user);
                    const sql = `UPDATE users SET last_logged_in = ? WHERE email = ?`;
                    db.query(sql, [moment().format(), email], (_, __) => {
                        return done(null, user);
                    });
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
                }
            });
        });
    }));

    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
        db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [user.id], (err, rows, fields) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (rows.length <= 0) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Record is not found in our database' });
            }
            const setUser = rows[0];
            done(err, setUser);
        });
    });
};
```

main.js

```js
// Initialization of Socket.io Connection
const socket = io("/");
let user;
function userInfo(u) {
    user = u;
}
// wss.registerSocketEvents(socket);
socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('connecting from client');
    // Test if emitting user is working
    socket.emit('current-user', {
        name: 'Woo Bear',
        email: "woo@live.com",
        socketId: socket.id,
    });
    registerSocketEvents(socket);
});

const getUser = (user) => {
    console.log(user);
};

// webRTCHandler.getLocalPreview();

// // Copy Personal Code - Add Event Listener - Click
// const personalCodeCopyButton = document.getElementById('personal_code_copy_button');
// personalCodeCopyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
//   const personalCode = store.getState().socketId;
//   navigator.clipboard && navigator.clipboard.writeText(personalCode);
// });

// // Add Event Listener - Chat and Video click
// const personalCodeChatButton = document.getElementById('personal_code_chat_button');
// const personalCodeVideoButton = document.getElementById('personal_code_video_button');
// personalCodeChatButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
//   console.log('chat click');
//   const personalCodeInput = document.getElementById('personal_code_input').value;
//   webRTCHandler.sendPreOffer(constants.callType.CHAT_PERSONAL_CODE, personalCodeInput);
// });

// personalCodeVideoButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
//   console.log('video click');
//   const personalCodeInput = document.getElementById('personal_code_input').value;
//   webRTCHandler.sendPreOffer(constants.callType.VIDEO_PERSONAL_CODE, personalCodeInput);
// });

// // event listeners for video call buttons
// const micButton = document.getElementById('mic_button');
// micButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
//   const localStream = store.getState().locatStream;
//   const micEnabled = localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled;
//   localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = !micEnabled;
//   ui.updateMicButton(micEnabled);
//   console.log(localStream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
// });

// const cameraButton = document.getElementById('camera_button');
// cameraButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
//   const localStream = store.getState().locatStream;
//   const cameraEnabled = localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled;
//   localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = !cameraEnabled;
//   ui.updateCameraButton(cameraEnabled);
// });

// const switchForScreenSharingButton = document.getElementById('screen_sharing_button');
// switchForScreenSharingButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
//   const screenSharingActive = store.getState().screenSharingActive;
//   webRTCHandler.switchBetweenCameraAndScreenSharing(screenSharingActive);
// });

// const newMessageInput = document.getElementById('new_message_input');
// newMessageInput.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
//   console.log('User types');
//   const key = event.key;

//   if (key === 'Enter') {
//     webRTCHandler.sendMessageUsingDataChannel(event.target.value);
//     ui.appendMessage(event.target.value, true);
//     newMessageInput.value = '';
//   }
// });

// const sendMessageButton = document.getElementById('send_message_button');
// sendMessageButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
//   webRTCHandler.sendMessageUsingDataChannel(newMessageInput.value);
//   ui.appendMessage(newMessageInput.value, true);
//   newMessageInput.value = '';
// });
```

welcome.ejs

```js
<%- include('includes/head.ejs') %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/video.css">
  </head>

  <body class="layout-top-nav" style="height: auto;">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <!-- Navbar -->
      <div class="display-none">
        <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark navbar-primary">
          <div class="container">
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
              <i class="text-white fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">GSL Translators</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="order-1 ml-auto order-md-3 navbar-nav navbar-no-expand">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                  More
                  <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <a href="/admin/profile" class="dropdown-item">
                    <i class="mr-2 fas fa-phone"></i> Contact
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                    <i class="mr-2 fas fa-info"></i> About
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <a href="/logout" class="dropdown-item">
                    <i class="mr-2 fas fa-power-off" aria-hidden="true"></i></i> Log out
                  </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- /.navbar -->

        <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
        <div class="content-wrapper" style="min-height: 520.5px;">
          <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
          <div class="content-header">
            <div class="container">

            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.content-header -->

          <!-- Main content -->
          <div class="content">
            <div class="container px-2">
              <div class="row">
                <% for (let i=0; i < 4; i++) { %>
                  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-sm">
                    <div class="card card-primary r-5 elevation-3">
                      <div class="p-0 card-body box-profile">
                        <div class="text-center">
                          <!-- <img class="profile-user-img img-fluid img-circle" src="img/user4-128x128.jpg"
                            alt="User profile picture"> -->
                          <img src="img/user4-128x128.jpg" class="rt-5" alt="user img"
                            style="width: 100%; max-height: 13rem;">
                        </div>

                        <div class="p-2 mb-2">
                          <h3 class="text-center profile-username">Cyril Eduafo</h3>

                          <p class="mb-1 text-center text-muted">0501395590</p>
                          <p class="mb-1 text-center text-muted">Available</p>
                          <p class="mb-1 text-center text-muted">
                            <i class="text-orange fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <i class="text-orange fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <i class="text-orange fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <i class="text-orange fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                          </p>

                          <div class="mt-2 text-center">
                            <button class="py-1 rounded btn-call bg-success w-25">
                              <i class="fa fa-video" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.card-body -->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <% } %>
              </div>
              <!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.content -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="hidden dialog"></div>
      <%- include('includes/footer.ejs') %>
      <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/ui-store.min.js"></script>
    <script src='store.js'></script>
    <!-- <script src='elements.js'></script>
    <script src='constants.js'></script>
    <script src='ui.js'></script> -->
    <script src='wss.js'></script>
    <!-- <script src='webRTCHandler.js'></script> -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Get user 
      userInfo(<%= user %>);
    </script>
    <%- typeof toastr != undefined ? toastr : ""%>
  </body>

  </html>
```

package.json

```
  {
  "name": "gsl_translators",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is for Toah's project work for his MSc ICT",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/ljsharp/gsl_translators.git"
  },
  "author": "Leslie Joe - LJ Sharp",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/ljsharp/gsl_translators/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ljsharp/gsl_translators#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fabrice8/ui-store": "^1.0.5",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "express-toastr": "^2.0.2",
    "express-validator": "^6.12.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.1.3",
    "storage-manager-js": "^4.0.6",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.12",
    "validator": "^13.6.0"
  }
}
```

Please I need your help to figure out what method or trick I can use to get current or logged-in users. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36821359/8201020

Comment: You can use the same algorithm and secret to verify the token.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!! I found this article - [Sharing Passport.Js Sessions With Both Express And Socket.Io](https://www.codementor.io/tips/0217388244/sharing-passport-js-sessions-with-both-express-and-socket-io) I can now get authenticated user data. Let me drop my code that fixes the issues of getting user info.

Add following package

```js
const session = require('express-session');
const sessionStore = new session.MemoryStore();
const passportSocketIo = require('passport.socketio');
const passport = require('passport');

app.use(session({
    secret : process.env.SECRET_KEY,
    saveUninitialized : true,
    resave : true,
    key: 'express.sid',
    store: sessionStore
}));

io.use(passportSocketIo.authorize({
    store: sessionStore,
    key: 'express.sid',
    passport: passport,
    cookieParser: cookieParser,
    secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY
}));
let connectedUsers = [];
io.on("connection", socket => {
    connectedUsers.push({
        ...socket.request.user,
        socketId: socket.id,
    });
    console.log(connectedUsers);
    // socket.on('current-user', (data) => {
    //     const connectedUser = {
    //         ...data,
    //         socketId: socket.id,
    //     };
    //     connectedUsers.push(connectedUser);
    //     console.log(connectedUsers);
    //     socket.emit('updatedUserLists', connectedUsers);
    // });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(socket.id);
        connectedUsers = connectedUsers.filter(function(u) {
            console.log(u);
            return u.socketId !== socket.id;
        });
        console.log(connectedUsers);
    });
});
```

Hope this may help someone else. Have a great day!