# Need Socket.io on Next js and Node.js to send a socket emit to a specific user only

Tags: node.js, next.js, socket.io

I know there are several posts about this but I've been trying several ways and also read a lot of documentation, however I don't seem to be able to make this work.

As the title says, I need that when a send a message to a specific user (usuarioActual.usuarioID), the message gets received by this user only.

this is what I currently have on the server:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {    
      
    socket.on('mensaje', (data) => {
      io.emit('mensaje', data); 
    });
  });
```

And this is the function on client side:

```
const enviarMensaje = (usuarioActual) => {
    socket.emit('mensaje', usuarioActual)
}
```

Please don't recommend some other posts as I've been reading a lot of them with no success so far. I would seriously appreciate some guidance on how to pass the socket id properly so I can make sure the message gets only received by the user with that socket id.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where in  your code are you trying to use a `socket.id` or is this somehow your own userID, not the id created by socket.io?  I don't see it anywhere in your code, so I don't really understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the authentication procedure for websockets [Authenticating socket io connections using JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788831/authenticating-socket-io-connections-using-jwt)

it wouldn't be authentication on the user specifically. But websockets work on  open tokens and secret tokens

Comment: Thanks for your response but sadly this doesn't really solve my problem.
I'm still not able to pass any socket id to the emit in order for only the specific user to get the message. 
Is there any other documentation I could check on for that?

Comment: socket.broadcast.to('ID').emit( 'send msg', {somedata : somedata_server} );

Comment: Thanks Sean. I've just tried this as well but it doesn't seem to work either so I'm now trying a different approach.
Basically I'm trying to set every user to join a room on connection, with auth._id being the name of the room. I'm importing auth from a provider and auth._id is the value of the _id of the mongodb user and it seems to be going through correctly in the console.
But it's still not working on the client side.